# Regular Expression for group

Tags: regex

I have a text were I need to find 3 groups strings.
I try expression: `\r?\n\r?\n\r?[0-9A-Z].*\d{7}` but I find only 2 strings instead 3.
I should highlight 00170784,HEDINV,00173575 but I get only 00170784 and 00173575 
This is the text:

```
BUY
USM4
200 contracts
04/28/2014 15:50
00170784
56
contracts
HEDINV
64
contracts
00173575
80
contracts
At average price of USD 134.375

SELL
USM4
200 contracts
04/28/2014 15:50
00170784
56
contracts
HEDINV
64
contracts
00173575
80
contracts
At average price of USD 134.5938
```

Comment: Why you want to highlight this `HEDINV` ? `\d{7}` in your regex won't match this.

Comment: What language are you using? Also, I can't get your regex to match what you're looking for... It would help if you explicitly stated what you wanted to capture, especially if there is a more efficient regex to be used...

Comment: We can't help if we don't know what you want to match and why. All we know is that you want to match `00170784`, `HEDINV`, and `00173575`, so, well, here you go: `00170784|HEDINV|00173575`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I suggest using this instead?

```
^\d{8}$|^[A-Z]{6}$
```

It has two capture groups it looks for. One is an 8 digit sequence for a whole line. The other is a 6 letter sequence for a whole line. That grabs what you're looking, unless there's a specific reason you're using all those linebreak matches.

Comment: Cool, @Natan. If this worked for you, please do me a favor and mark my answer as accepted with the Checkmark next to it :)